# Creating a json object in swift: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I'm new in swift and ran through some demos on creating a json object and I'm trying to create one to test some of my classes. From what I can see everything looks fine, but am new so maybe missing something.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let contactRecords = [
        "listId" : 1,
        "phoneContacts": [{
            "phoneNumber": "264",
            "id": 1,
            "listID": 1,
            "orderID": 0,
            "description": "Call First During the Day",
            "dispatchDispositions": "",
            "viewFromWeb": false,
            "name": "Office",
            "uniqueId": 1,
            "readOnly": false,
            "changed": false
            },{
            "phoneNumber": "99999999",
            "id": 1,
            "listID": 1,
            "orderID": 0,
            "description": "",
            "dispatchDispositions": "",
            "viewFromWeb": false,
            "name": "Cell Phone",
            "uniqueId": 1,
            "readOnly": false,
            "changed": false
            }],
        
        ] as [String : Any]
```

I got the error in xcode Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ':'

I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong, it looks like the json objects from every demo I can find. What do you all see?

Comment: What are the braces for? This is not JSON.

Comment: As vadian has already mentioned this is not valid Swift syntax. What you are trying to create a dictionary or a json string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up the dictionary and the JSON string syntax. It’s either a Swift dictionary without any braces

```
let contactRecords : [String:Any] = [
    "listId" : 1,
    "phoneContacts": [[
        "phoneNumber": "264",
        "id": 1,
        "listID": 1,
        "orderID": 0,
        "description": "Call First During the Day",
        "dispatchDispositions": "",
        "viewFromWeb": false,
        "name": "Office",
        "uniqueId": 1,
        "readOnly": false,
        "changed": false
        ],[
        "phoneNumber": "99999999",
        "id": 1,
        "listID": 1,
        "orderID": 0,
        "description": "",
        "dispatchDispositions": "",
        "viewFromWeb": false,
        "name": "Cell Phone",
        "uniqueId": 1,
        "readOnly": false,
        "changed": false
        ]]
    ]
```

or a literal JSON string with enclosing braces

```
let contactRecords = 
"""
{   "listId" : 1,
    "phoneContacts": [{
        "phoneNumber": "264",
        "id": 1,
        "listID": 1,
        "orderID": 0,
        "description": "Call First During the Day",
        "dispatchDispositions": "",
        "viewFromWeb": false,
        "name": "Office",
        "uniqueId": 1,
        "readOnly": false,
        "changed": false
        },{
        "phoneNumber": "99999999",
        "id": 1,
        "listID": 1,
        "orderID": 0,
        "description": "",
        "dispatchDispositions": "",
        "viewFromWeb": false,
        "name": "Cell Phone",
        "uniqueId": 1,
        "readOnly": false,
        "changed": false
        }]
 }
 """
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I guess I was confusing the two types. The first project I have to work with json coming in and was confused.